# Help with a phone which shows nothing but the boot screen

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, clockworkmod-recovery, karbonn, karbonn-a10, karbonn-a15

I have an Android phone that isn't starting up. All it shows when I power it on is the boot up screen. The recovery mode does not start and the ADB shell on my laptop fails to detect the device as well. What can I possibly do to get my device running again. I don't mind formatting the phone. The device is a Karbonn Titanium S1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Updated:

- The `adb devices` command detects the device as long as it is switched off and connected to the PC via USB.
- `adb shell` -> `recovery --wipe_data` gives a segmentation fault '139' error.
- Trying to boot the phone at times ends up  in a screen that says:

> **Encryption unsuccessful**
>
> Encryption was interrupted and can't complete. As a result, the data
>   on your tablet is no longer accessible.
>
> To resume using your tablet, you must perform a factory reset. When
>   you set up your tablet after the reset, you'll have an opportunity to
>   restore any data that was backed up to your Google Account.

- The phone does not boot into recovery mode the manual way but does enter a frozen recovery mode when I run the `adb reboot recovery` command with an "data mounted failed" error.

Comment: How about querying Google with `phone stuck at boot screen` OR `Karbonn Titanium stuck at boot screen`?

Comment: So, have you considered flashing the phone? There is a tool well known for flashing. I'm not sure whether it would work on a Qualcomm device as well because its explicitly not mentioned there. However, your device's Stock ROM is hosted on the same website. http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool

Comment: I need the scatter loading file and I can't locate it. Does it exist for Qualcomm based devices?

Comment: @Firelord: SP Flash Tool didn't work for me. :-(
There is Suite of tools from Qualcomm too that I managed to download. But they didn't help either. For some peculiar reason, adb detects the phone in recovery mode and also when the phone is switched on to give that error message. But none of the software I downloaded in the past 10 days seem to detect the phone. What could be wrong possibly? Is there a way I can revive my device through adb alone (not even fastboot)? Because the phone is unresponsive and software don't detect the device. But the ADB works fine. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to flash your phone with a stock ROM. Search for the procedure online or take it to the service centre if you are not confident enough.

Comment: It is more of a comment than an answer. Please mention the sources and also write the relevant part here in the answer.

Comment: Please edit your answer so it pertains to answering the OP's question, as it stands it should be a comment, otherwise it will get flagged. As Firelord suggested, add sources and anything relevant.